# RadTreeView OnClientNodeClicking corfirm

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have problem confirming if node should be changed or not, with jConfirm.

This is my js code:

```
function OnClientNodeClicking(sender, args) {                                        

   var calcelTrue = confirm('Can you confirm this?')
   if (calcelTrue == false) 
   {
      args.set_cancel(true);
      return true;
   }                           

}
```

and it works fine. But now i want to use jConfirm. And the program does not want to wait for me to click OK or Cancel (it just fire the event). So I am trying to stop the event and if I will click Ok then the event of clicking on node should fire again from js.

```
function OnClientNodeClicking(sender, args) {                                        

   var node = args.get_node();

   jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {

          if (r){

                * Fire the event of clicking  
          }
   });

   args.set_cancel(true);                              

        }                  
   }
```

How can I fire the event from js or how can I prevent jConfirm to wait for me to chose and then triger the event.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?

```
function OnClientNodeClicking(sender, args) {    
  jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (ans) 
  {                 
       if (!ans)                     
       args.set_cancel(true);             
  }); 
}
```

Comment: This does not work, becouse before I even click OK the page redirect to diferent page (node).

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by using link button postback when Ok is clicked and then in code behind fire event changeNode().

Javascript:

```
    var node = args.get_node();

     jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {
     if (r) { // Ok clicked
          node.set_selected(true);
          __doPostBack('<%= this.LinkButton5.UniqueID %>', '');
          return true;
     }
    });

args.set_cancel(true);  // Cancell the event
```

Code behind:

```
protected void bChangeNode(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     rtvNode_Click(rtvMeni.SelectedNode.Text, rtvMeni.SelectedNode.Value);
 }
```